# Putting a space between two different tables in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want about 30 tables on a page in a grid like format but I am having trouble putting any spacing between all of them. This is what I have right now:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #6666ff;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.prizestitle {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.prizesinfo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.prizesdesc {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ohLa00m7/1/

Something similar to how to boxes are layed out here (http://www.awwwards.com/blog/) is what I am looking for.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's not a grid if it doesn't line up horizontally.  The page you linked to uses a javascript based responsive layout manager called [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to position the tiles in columns based on the available screen space (try resizing browser).  It is more than just HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<div>` instead of tables would work better.

My version of this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="shell">
    <div class="prizestitle">Table</div>
    <div class="prizesinfo td">Info</div>
    <div class="prizesdesc td">Description</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.td {
padding: 8px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.prizestitle {
padding: 8px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
background-color: #6666ff;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 200;

}

.prizesinfo {
    font-size: 25px;

}

.prizesdesc {
    font-size: 18px;

}

.shell {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: calc(50% - 40px);
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works really well, but I have decided to use semantic ui instead. Good alternative to plain tables though :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use **margin** and **calc** function in css :

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #6666ff;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.prizestitle {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.prizesinfo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.prizesdesc {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply just adding a margin to the table will add spaces between tables
But I would tell you that it's impossible to achieve the result as you have shown by using tables to do so you should replace them with Divs and you may need to use some javascript libraries.

to add a margin:

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid gray;
width: 50%;
float: left;
margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this CSS does what you want

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

You can adjust the width percentage and margin to get different spacing and tables per line.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is kinda stupid but you can just add empty paragraphs in between each table

```
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>       </p>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>       </p>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th><span class="prizestitle">Table</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="prizesinfo">Info</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="prizesdesc">Description</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 <table cellspacing="10">
```

but it doesn't work in HTML 5 as far as I know.

Or in the CSS insert something like this:

```
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<table cellspacing="10">
```

Comment: `cellspacing` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You may play around making border wider and include this width into size of the table container like

```
table {
   border: 10px solid gray;
   width: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
}
```